# Apache Server Not Loading in New Resources

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, web

I'm currently building a website using PHP and using Apache for the web server. I recently added some sub-folders to my images folder and am trying to load in those images on the site. However, the images aren't loading, and when I view the sources tab in DevTools, I'm seeing that it's not even loading in the new folders I've added, as well as some test images I've tried adding in. It had no issues with the initial dump of files I gave it, but won't load any new folders/images:

[Images directory with new folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utRRa.png)

[Sources tab only loading original image files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPrxX.png)

Below is the PHP code that loads images onto the page:

```
 <?php
                $newsSql = "SELECT newsID, newsTitle, newsDescription, newsPicturePath, newsPicAlt, newsURL, newsBtnText FROM news_items ORDER BY newsID DESC";
                $newsResult = $conn->query($newsSql);

                if ($newsResult->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $newsResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<div class="row justify-content-center">';
                        echo '    <div class="card contentC">';
                        echo '        <img src="' . $row["newsPicturePath"] .'" class="card-img-top" alt="' . $row["newsPicAlt"] .'">';
                        echo '        <div class="card-body">';
                        echo '            <h5 class="card-title">' . $row["newsTitle"] .'</h5>';
                        echo '            <p class="card-text cardC">' . $row["newsDescription"] .'</p>';
                        echo '            <a href="' . $row["newsURL"] .'" onclick="cardClick(\'' . $row["newsTitle"] .'\')" class="btn btn-secondary text-dark">' . $row["newsBtnText"] .'</a>';
                        echo '        </div>';
                        echo '    </div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

It's definitely going to be something simple and stupid but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Can you show how did you load those images? what kind of syntax did you use to load those images?

Comment: @DUDEZKIE Sure, editing in the code for the image loading. As for how I add the images to the Apache server, I'm just drag and dropping the files into the folder: it's just a localhost on my Windows PC.

Comment: What I mean is how do you display it on your web application? something like <img src="/dir/image.jpg".... etc.

Comment: Yeah just finished adding in the code, editor was being finicky with the format for the codeblock. The picturePath variable is a string for "src/images/news/news1.jpg" etc. I have it set to be relative to where my localhost folder starts.

Comment: Remember that the browser loads images over HTTP relative to the current page URL. They need to be served from your web server. What is the URL of the page you're loading in your browser? Which folder is your document root?

Comment: have you tried manually check if the browser can read the file using this? http://localhost/project_name/src/images/news/news1.jpg

Comment: @DUDEZKIE thank you for making me go back through to add in the code. Noticed that in my strings for the PicturePaths the .jpg was actually ,jpg. All good now!

Comment: good news! congrats!

Answer (score -1):

There was nothing wrong with my Apache environment or my code; was victim to commas instead of periods in strings I was passing for image paths.

Called it that it was something stupid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).